# AC to DC converter device (AC adapter) with adjustable output voltage and adjustable output current

Tags: ac, dc, converter, adapter, device

Is there a device available in the market that can take an input AC from mains and convert it into DC and output it, **the output current** and voltage must be adjustable.
I know there are AC adapters with adjustable output voltage but no adjustable output current. I'm looking for an AC adapter that allows me adjust both the output voltage and the output current and not just the output voltage.

Comment: Please do not ask for product recommendations. And you can't regulate voltage and current at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term you are looking for is "bench power supply". Note that the current setting is a *limit*.

Some reading on the subject: [Does a hobbyist need a bench power supply?](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/chat/does-a-hobbyist-need-a-bench-power-supply/) and [What is a Bench Power Supply?](https://uk.tek.com/blog/bench-power-supply-basics).

Comment: Looked at from another viewpoint, when in current regulation, the voltage setting is also a limit.

Answer (score 0):

It is theoretically impossible for a power supply to regulate current and voltage at the same time. The most that is possible if for either current or voltage to be adjustable with a limit set of the other. If the unregulated parameter reaches the limit then the other parameter value is reduced to whatever value is necessary to prevent the limited value to be exceeded.

It is possible for a power supply to have a switch the determines which parameter is regulated and which is limited.